# JAVA threads dont seem to work

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making a simple java game to learn it. I want a program with a square witch you can click and it changes color, than I dont want to be able to klick it for 8 seconds. I Know I dont make timer get any higher, I do this on purpose to check if a can quit it first before using sleep.

While is Do this my program gets stuck and I cant close it, so i try threads but it still doesnt work. Can someone tell me  what I'm doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class ViewControll extends JFrame
{
JPanel playerPanel;
Dimension playerPlotDimension;
Plot plot00;
Thread t;

public ViewControll()
{
    playerPlotDimension=new Dimension(200,200);
    plot00 = new Plot(playerPlotDimension);
    t= new Thread(plot00);
    createAndShowGUI();
}

private void createAndShowGUI()
{
    setTitle("ALPHA 0.1");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setSize(400,400);
    setVisible(true); 
    t.start();
    add(plot00);      

}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new ViewControll();
}


}
```

And here the second Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Plot extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
int plotstate;
int timer;

public Plot(Dimension playerPlotDimension)
{
    plotstate =0;
    timer =0;
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setPreferredSize(playerPlotDimension);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY,5,true));
    setToolTipText("Werkt Dit?");   
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    { 
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) 
          { 

            switch (plotstate) 
            {
                case 0: setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        plotstate = 1;
                break;
                case 1: setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                        while (timer != 8)
                        {
                        plotstate =0;
                        }
                break;
            }
          } 
    }); 

}







}
```

Comment: Where are you incrementing the timer?

Comment: All that your thread does is add a MouseListener. Performing this operation in another thread will not make any difference; the listener itself will be called on the event dispatch thread.

Comment: I removed the timer increment to test if it would stay in the loop. So I'm using the threads wrong? how should i be useing it than ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this, is this a good sollution?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Plot extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
int plotstate;
int growtimer;

public Plot(Dimension playerPlotDimension)
{
    plotstate =0;
    growtimer =0;
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setPreferredSize(playerPlotDimension);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY,5,true));
    setToolTipText("Werkt Dit?");

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    { 
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) 
          { 

            switch (plotstate) 
            {
                case 0: setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        plotstate = 1;
                break;
                case 1: setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                        run();
                break;
            }
          } 
    }); 


}


@Override
public void run() 
{
    while (growtimer != 8)
    {
        plotstate =0;
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        growtimer++;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Plot#run() method increments growtimer eight times in eight seconds, but what does that accomplish?  Where in your code does anything look at growtimer?

Comment: I want it to sleep for 8 seconds and after that change its plotstate..... and i just answered my own question... why do I use a while loop, i don't need it haha

Answer (score 0):

If you want your plot to be "disabled" for 8 sec, why don't you just store the click time and then ignore subsequent clicks while the 8 sec are not past ?
something like that:

```
public class Plot extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
int plotstate;
long clicktime;
...
public Plot(Dimension playerPlotDimension)
{
    plotstate =0;
    growtimer =0;
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setPreferredSize(playerPlotDimension);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY,5,true));
    setToolTipText("Werkt Dit?");

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() 
    { 
          public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) 
          { 

            switch (plotstate) 
            {
                case 0: setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                        plotstate = 1;
                        clicktime = System.currentMillis();
                break;
                case 1: setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                        if (System.currentMillis() - clicktime > 8000)
                        {
                         plotstate = 0;
                        }
                break;
            }
          } 
    }); 


}
```